# Generate Cassandra friendly relation in Pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

Using the Pig example from [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/analytics/about_pig), you can load data from Cassandra by

```
cassandra_data = LOAD 'cassandra://PigDemo/Scores' USING CassandraStorage()
   AS (name, columns: bag {T: tuple(score, value)});
```

Next you can for example compute aggregates by

```
total_scores = FOREACH cassandra_data GENERATE name, COUNT(columns.score) as counts,
   LongSum(columns.score) as total;
```

After reading the Pig reference [manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html), it is not obvious to me how i can rewrite/extend above code to produce a relation that I can store back into Cassandra. It should have the format

```
(<row_key>,{(<column_name1>,<value1>),(<column_name2>,<value2>)})
```

In our case

```
(name,{('counts',counts),('total',total)})
```

I have unsuccessfully attempted using *AS* and specifying a [schema](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Schemas), and I tried to do it by using an additional *GROUP* statement:

```
grouped  = GROUP total_scores by name;
cass_in = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, total_scores.(co,total);
```

However, I feel there must be a straight-forward way that I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the full line of the code you wrote to store records into cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

Use the TOBAG() and TOTUPLE() UDFs (since 0.8)

```
FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, TOBAG(TOTUPLE('counts', total_scores.counts), TOTUPLE('total', total_scores.total));
```